# MS Azure - Can I assign Reserved IP to a running VM created using the ARM model?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

MS Azure - Can I assign Reserved IP to a running VM created using the ARM model?

There is no static IP when VM was created.

in AWS I can create Elastic IP and assign to a VM. I was hoping to do the same here but cannot seem to find the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer for ARM VM [How to reserve IP when provisioning Azure VM (resource manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021375/how-to-reserve-ip-when-provisioning-azure-vm-resource-manager)

For classic VMs it is very straightforward. Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -ServiceName TestService